# seems like #import header files are being crossed error

Tags: ios

Im not sure what happened, but I didnt touch anything and suddenly the #import .h files on the .m files are recognizing objects that havent been imported:
For example Car*carsample...
is recognized even though i havent imported Car.h

any thoughts?
thanks

Comment: Did you and anything new to your precompiled header? `.pch` file

Comment: This is impossible to answer without sample code of the .h and .m files that you're inquiring about. You could have set `Car` in one of those files, and it's delegate is hanging on to it inside of whatever file you're currently working with.

Comment: that file is so long... the issue is when trying to access a property of a certain object created  car.name (works) but for some reason the mutable array doesnt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had duplicate Car.h files in my project directory (the folder with your app folders) so I deleted the old one, it worked fine after.